# How/when did Rukia and Renji find out about Ichigo's inner hollow, and did everybody else know around the same the same time too?

Tags: bleach

How is it that Rukia and Renji knew about Ichigo's inner hollow during the Arrancar arc despite Ichigo not mentioning anything about it to either of them, and how long have they known? I'm also wondering as to who else would have known about it around that time as well (besides the obvious people like Urahara, Yuroichi, and Ichigo's father)?